# My app is crashing in different region due to date format

Tags: swift, xcode, datetime, swift5

My app is crashing in different country. When I changed my system time zone, it showing nil. I got date time string from API. Firtly, I convert it in date then to string for date, Its not giving the correct date time after conversion.Kindly help me out
My date string is - "6/30/2020 12:07:01 AM"

For string to date:-

```
static func stringToDate(dateString:String)->Date{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateString)!
    return date
}
```

for date to string

```
 static func dateToString(date:Date)->String{
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a"
       let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

       return dateString
   }
```

It is crashing in other region.

Comment: In which function does it crash and can you give an example of regions where it works and where it crash?

Comment: Its working in India, it's not crashing in simulator  but crashing in the US

Comment: You didn't answer the first part of my question, where in the code does it crash?

Comment: while converting string to date

Comment: You say you get the string from an api so I assumed it would always be the same format but obviously it isn’t (unless you are doing something with the string) so _you_ need to check the documentation for the api and investigate why the string can contain dates with different formats. I suggest you delete this question because to me it looks like only you can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using let use if let ,

```
static func stringToDate(dateString:String)->Date?{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateString) {
    return date
  } else { 
    //code what to do if date format does not match
    return nil
 }
}


    static func dateToString(date:Date)->String{
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a"
       if let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
       {
         return dateString
       } else {
       //code what to do if date format does not match
        return ""
      }
   }
```